# Visibility of Dynamically Declared Field in PHP

Tags: php, class, field, visibility, variable-declaration

What's the visibility (`public`, `private`, ...) of a field that dynamically has been declared (in PHP)?

```
class Foo {
    public function __construct() {
        $this->dynamicallyDeclaredField = $aValue;
    }
}
```

Comment: its public, if you mean the default modifier

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's `public`.

I don't know why. Just tested it.